# Free download manager issue in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

So Im not really sure why/how/when this happened, but just today, every time I try to download something from the web using Chrome, I am getting this page:

[image: Screenshot]

> Free Download Manager is not properly installed! Please reinstall Free Download Manager.
>
> If you want to download with your browser please remove "npfdm.dll" file in the Plugin directory of your browser.
>
> Error code: 80040154.

It seems a little... sketch... because I honestly do not know what to make of it, or what the problem was, or where it even came from. Suffice it to say, I an unable to currently download anything.

My Microsoft Security Essentials is running in the background and doesnt seem to show any virus activity... so I am not really sure what to make of this, or how to get rid of it. Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You installed an extension or plugin. If it happened without your knowledge, then you should run a malware scan and consider using a fresh install of Chrome and/or a fresh profile. (I highly recommend scanning anyway because it is [not in the webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/free%20download%20manager).)

Either way, you can disable or remove it by checking the following two pages for *Free Download Manager*:

- `chrome://extensions`
- `chrome://plugins`

Comment: Ok, thank you. The problem is that I cannot seem to find where Chrome is on my PC...where exactly is it?...

Comment: Also, can you please recommend a malware scanner for this purpose? All I currently use now is just Microsoft Security Essentials.

Comment: I don’t understand your problem or question; you said and the screenshot shows that you are using it, so how can you not know where it is? And there is a [thread here](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/) with a lot of discussion and suggestions for anti-malware.

Comment: No, what I mean is, you said to check Chrome://plugins. Where is this directory on my computer?

Comment: Those aren’t directories, they’re *pages*. Type those URLs into the Omnibar.

Comment: Ah ok thank you. I found the .dll file and deleted it from my computer in the plugin directory and this seems to have stopped the problem. I didnt find it in the plugins page though. But all seems well now... thanks! :)

Comment: That’s not the best way to do it because it leaves traces of the plugin/extension in the browser which could cause problems. You should remove it from the *Extensions*/*Plugins* pages because doing it manually is a lot more difficult/risky. Did you check the *Extensions* page?

Answer (score 0):

Free Download Manager is **NOT malware**. It's a legitimate piece of software, and you probably installed the chrome plugin during the installation procedure without realizing it.

Your actual problem is the fact that the plugin/dll/program is failing for some odd reason. Follow the steps below to remove Chrome integration.

Go to your Options->Settings page:

[image: Step1_Menu]

Go to Downloads->Monitoring. In there, untick Google Chrome, so that FreeDownloadManager integration with chrome is disabled. This should prevent the popup, regardless if the dll/plugin is working or not.

[image]

Disclaimer: I use free download manager.